# Analog of nslookup's ls command in java program

Tags: java, nslookup

What technology can be used to implement analog of nslookup's `ls` command in a java program?

For example, it would receive 'com' as a parameter and return a list of strings with all domain names under '.com'.

Windows implementation of `ls` command: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490725.aspx

Unix implementation seems to have all but disappeared, even though it worked fine a few years back.

Comment: nslookup does not do that.  A list of all domains under `.com` would be gigabytes of data.

Comment: Size of data is a non-issue.

Comment: nslookup does not enumerate contents of domains.

Comment: If you believe so, it's Okay. The question is about java, not about nslookup.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) has a 'whois' client for Java.  [Example usage here.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-whois-example/)

Comment: Not exactly a sub-domain listing, or am I missing anything?